# Is there a way to order execution of @KafkaListener methods?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Currently I have 2 @KafkaListener methods that consume events from two different topics. The problem is that I need to "make" one of them execute first, always, and then the second one. I tried @DependsOn. Thanks

Update: Description of my system is following
I have kafka topic Account and TransactionRequest. I have microservice called datagenerator which on start generates 10.000 accounts, and 1 transaction every 300ms that includes accountid, amount etc. The problem is that microservice validationService listens for Accounts and TransactionRequests, and in my @KafkaListener method called validate, i have method that validates incoming transactions. Another @KafkaListener listens for accounts and as soon as they start generating, this method insertAccounts inserts them into cassandra DB. The problem is, first kafkaListener validate tries to check amount on account in DB, but they havent been inserted because @KafkaListener responsible for that didnt fire yet.

Comment: What's the use case? Couldn't you make one of the listeners use a producer to the topic that the second listener reads from rather than working around Kafka client limitations?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - interesting, could you give me some example of how that works?

Comment: I dont really understand how to use a producer as a listener? That sounds like proper way to do it. If you can, link me some resources or code example.

Comment: You inject a KafkaTemplate to the class with a listener annotated method. You don't "use producer **as** listener" ; you use it **in** a listener. Same like you would for any other method. Examples are already in the Spring Kafka documentation for using KafkaTemplate send method